# How to select first and last record from ordered query without UNION, INTERSECT etc

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, union

So, I admit it was one of my exam tasks yesterday and I failed to deal with it...
I had simple database of people with their name, salary and function (A, B, C, D, E and F) and I had to select functions that have the biggest and the lowest avg salary. I had also to ignore function C. 
Example of database:

```
name      salary      function
Mike        100          A
John        200          F
Jenny       500          B
Fred        400          B
...         250          C
...         800          D
...         100          E
...         350          E
...         450          F
...         250          A
...         500          B
```

Example of result:

```
function          avg salary
  A                  300
  C                  600
```

I know how to do it using UNION as in oracle I can group by function order by salary, union that with order by salary desc and for example fetch 1 rows only in both selects. I could have used WHERE but it's impossible to use WHERE with aggregation (like AVG(salary)), but how to do it in single query without UNION, MINUS or INTERSECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @vkp's approach, but without the join back to the base table:

```
select function, avg_salary
from (
  select function, avg(salary) as avg_salary,
    rank() over (order by avg(salary)) as rnk_asc,
    rank() over (order by avg(salary) desc) as rnk_desc
  from tablename
  group by function
)
where rnk_asc = 1 or rnk_desc = 1;

F AVG_SALARY
- ----------
D        800
A        175
```

The two `rank()` calls put each function/average in order:

```
select function, avg(salary) as avg_salary,
  rank() over (order by avg(salary)) as rnk_asc,
  rank() over (order by avg(salary) desc) as rnk_desc
from tablename
group by function;

F AVG_SALARY    RNK_ASC   RNK_DESC
- ---------- ---------- ----------
D        800          6          1
B    4.7E+02          5          2
F        325          4          3
C        250          3          4
E        225          2          5
A        175          1          6
```

That forms the inline view; the outer query then just selects the rows ranked 1 in either of the generated columns, which is D and A here.

If you had two functions with the same average salary then they would get the same rank, and both ranked as 1 then you'd see both; so you can get more than two results. That may be what you want. If not you can avoid it by defining how to break ties, either with `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Comment: yup, that's more elegant. Thank you very much for being interested and help :) You also have a little mistake as I needed AVG not SUM, but your idea is great. Thank you 1 more :) PS. I see you've already repaired you're mistake ::)

Comment: @RIPI - I already noticed and corrected that, sorry. (Only noticed 'cos I got a different answer to vkp!)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rank` function (use `dense_rank` if there can be ties in averages) to order rows by their average salary. Then select the highest and lowest ranked rows.

```
select t1.function, avg(t1.salary)
from (select 
       rank() over(order by avg(salary) desc) rnk_high
      ,rank() over(order by avg(salary)) rnk_low
      ,function 
      from tablename
      group by function) t 
join tablename t1 on t.function = t1.function
where rnk_high = 1 or rnk_low = 1
group by t1.function
```

Comment: oh, it works. Thank you. That was pretty easy. If you care, in last lane it should've been GROUP BY t.function in your solution, but it's perfect anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return *exactly one* min/max row you probably get a better plan when you avoid two different ORDER BY:

```
select function, avg_salary
from (
  select function, avg(salary) as avg_salary,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by avg(salary)) as rnk_asc,
    COUNT(*) over () as cnt
  from tablename
  group by function
)
where rnk_asc = 1 or rnk_asc = cnt;
```

Caution, RANK will fail if there are two rows with the same MAX value (no row where `rnk_asc = cnt`).

Comment: You only avoid one window sort; with the analytics it doesn't have the same issue you can get trying to find the min and max aggregates at the same time, which can ignore indexes - not sure if that's what you're thinking of. But that is still slightly better.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I'm used to work with really large amounts of data (DWHs, although not on PG) and there one sort less might be a huge difference :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use subquery in Oracle ? 
try this

```
Select z.Function from 
   (Select Function, Avg(Salary) avgSal
    from tableName
    group By function) z
Where z.avgSal = (Select Max(z0.avgSal) 
                  from (Select Avg(Salary) avgSal
                        from tableName
                        group By function) z0)
  Or z.avgSal = (Select Min(z1.avgSal) 
                  from (Select Avg(Salary) avgSal
                        from tableName
                        group By function) z1)
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the alias in the group-by clauses; `group By function`, rather than `group By function f`. But you also aren't showing the actual average, just finding the functions. Guess it just needs `z.avgSal` in the outer select list?

Comment: ahhh yes! typo! Thanks!